# Как собрать корректный ассоциативный массив и отправить его методом пост?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Собираю массив примерно такого вида (пример в низу)

Если посмотреть в консоль браузера то массив имеет родительские элементы а в случае с Оренбургом и дочерние.

Но если я пытаюсь отправить его на сервер, то туда приходят только родительские элементы, аналогично будет если я выполняю функцию `JSON.stringify(myArray)`. Вставил ее так как перед отправкой массива на сервер я его конвертирую в json

Мне кажется я собираю какой то неправильный массив.
В случае, если я собираю элементы в объект то все нормально, но мне нужно иметь именно многомерный ассоциативный массив и не конвертировать объект в массив на сервере.

```js
var myArray = {};
$('.parrent>li').each(function(i, li) {
  var key = $(li).data('name');
  var name = $(li).children('span').text();
  myArray[key] = [];
  myArray[key][name] = [];
  $(li).find('ul>li').each(function(j, subli) {
    var subkey = $(subli).data('name');
    var subname = $(subli).children('span').text();


    myArray[key][name][subkey] = subname;

  })
});
console.log(myArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parrent">
  <li data-name="city-Москва"><span>Москва</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Вологда"><span>Вологда</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Оренбург"><span>Оренбург</span>
    <ul>
      <li data-name="city-Бугуруслан"><span>Бугуруслан</span></li>
      <li data-name="city-Орск"><span>Орск</span></li>
      <li data-name="city-Новотроицк"><span>Новотроицк</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-name="city-Самара"><span>Самара</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Саратов"><span>Саратов</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы работаете с массивом, как с объектом

```
  myArray[key] = [];
  myArray[key][name] = [];
  $(li).find('ul>li').each(function(j, subli) {
    var subkey = $(subli).data('name');
    var subname = $(subli).children('span').text();

    myArray[key][name][subkey] = subname;

  })
```

Вот здесь у вас `myArray[key][name]` - это массив, в который вы пытаетесь добавить св-во по ключу, значкению `subkey`. Оно добавляется, но при превращении в `json` не учитывается. Либо делайте объект, либо вложенные элементы будут в массиве по индексу, а не по ключу

Вариант с объектом:

```js
const myArray = {};
$('.parrent>li').each(function(i, li) {
  const key = $(li).data('name');
  const name = $(li).children('span').text();
  myArray[key] = {};
  myArray[key][name] = {};
  $(li).find('ul>li').each(function(j, subli) {
    const subkey = $(subli).data('name');
    var subname = $(subli).children('span').text();

    myArray[key][name][subkey] = subname;

  })
});
console.log(myArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parrent">
  <li data-name="city-Москва"><span>Москва</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Вологда"><span>Вологда</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Оренбург"><span>Оренбург</span>
    <ul>
      <li data-name="city-Бугуруслан"><span>Бугуруслан</span></li>
      <li data-name="city-Орск"><span>Орск</span></li>
      <li data-name="city-Новотроицк"><span>Новотроицк</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-name="city-Самара"><span>Самара</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Саратов"><span>Саратов</span></li>
</ul>
```

Вариант с массивом:

```js
const myArray = {};
$('.parrent>li').each(function(i, li) {
  const key = $(li).data('name');
  const name = $(li).children('span').text();
  myArray[key] = [];
  myArray[key][0] = [name];
  
  const $subEls = $(li).find('ul>li');
  if($subEls.length) {
    myArray[key][1] = [];
    $subEls.each(function(j, subli) {
      const subkey = $(subli).data('name');
      const subname = $(subli).children('span').text();
      myArray[key][1][j] = subname;

    })
  }
});
console.log(myArray);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parrent">
  <li data-name="city-Москва"><span>Москва</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Вологда"><span>Вологда</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Оренбург"><span>Оренбург</span>
    <ul>
      <li data-name="city-Бугуруслан"><span>Бугуруслан</span></li>
      <li data-name="city-Орск"><span>Орск</span></li>
      <li data-name="city-Новотроицк"><span>Новотроицк</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-name="city-Самара"><span>Самара</span></li>
  <li data-name="city-Саратов"><span>Саратов</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `myArray[key][0] = [name];` кадратные скобки у name обязательны, или тут можно опустить?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов квадратные скобки здесь для того, чтобы `name` был в массиве..